# Which one is correct $\sqrt D$ or $\sqrt[3] D?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory

The discriminant of a quadratic equation

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is $ D =  { b^2 – 4ac}$

Generally we used square root before  $D$ in quadratic equation i,e  $\sqrt D = \sqrt { b^2 – 4ac}$  because  $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

Cubic equations also have a discriminant. For a cubic equation

$ax³ + bx² + cx + d = 0$

The discriminant is given by

$D = 18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2.$

**My confusion**:For  cubic  $\sqrt D= \sqrt{18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2}$  or $\sqrt[3] D= \sqrt[3]{18abcd – 4b^3d + b^2c^2 – 4ac^3 – 27a^2d^2}$

Which one  is correct  $\sqrt D$ or $\sqrt[3] D?$

My question is that  in cubic   what do  we  used  square  root or cubic root before  $D$?

Actually  I was   trying the find the  Galois  group of  polynomial  $x^3-x  +1$  Here i got $D=-23$

So  i think  the  splitting  field  is  $F[\sqrt{-23}]$.Then  Galois  group will  of order $2$

Comment: I don't understand the question. $\sqrt{D}$ and $\sqrt[3]{D}$ are different expressions. What do you mean by "Which one is correct"? Correct in what context?

Comment: Once you define $D$ for a cubic your expressions for $\sqrt D$ and $\sqrt[3] D$ are correct.  The one for $\sqrt D$ may have trouble when $D$ is negative.  The real question is which one is useful.

Comment: The Galois group can't have order 2 since the polynomial is irreducible. Let $a$ be the real root. Then $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is a subfield of the splitting field and it has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple square root of the discriminant (i.e., $\sqrt \Delta$), since $\Delta := a^4 \cdot \left((x_1 \cdot ​{x_2}^2​ + x_2​ \cdot {x_3}^2​ + x_3​ \cdot {x_1}^2​)−({x_1}^2​ \cdot x_2​ + {x_2}^2 \cdot ​x_3​ + {x_3}^2 \cdot ​x_1​) \right)^2$.

Comment: Basically (from the above), it follows that $\sqrt \Delta$ is equal to $a^2 \cdot \left((r_1-r_2) \cdot (r_1-r_3) \cdot (r_2-r_3) \right)$, where $a$ is the coefficient of $x^3$ and $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$ are the roots of our cubic equation.
P.S. The Galois groups we have are just $A_3$ or $S_3$ and $\sqrt \Delta$ is fixed with respect to the above only if the first of the two aforementioned cases occurs.